# Extract Data from Multiple SpreadSheets using Active X User Form Interface

Tags: database, excel, vba

I am a complete rookie in VBA. Please excuse me if my questions might seem stupid.

What I want to do is to create a User form interface in Excel for extracting futures price data. I have around hundred different spreadsheet with futures prices named like 08012, 08011 and so on. I have similar spreadsheets with forecasts for the same futures and they are also named in the same fashion. I want to create such Graphical User Interface that one can enter stock symbol, date range and either forecast or real price and obtain the desired series from the correct spreadsheet. My biggest problem is that I am complete rookie in VBA so I do not even know if this is possible to solve that kind of problem in Excel.

I have been reading some literature and I realized that I needed an User Form Interface with 2 text boxes( one for stock symbol look ,the one for time range ) as well as an option box( to decide whether to display forecast or real price) . But that's all I can not really understand how to pass the data user enters further in the program so Excel indeed fetches correct stock from correct spreadsheet.

Any tips, links to similar problems would be very welcome ! Sorry the problem description is unclear. Please ask any details you need.
Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a As String
Dim aa As String
Dim myP As Range
Dim myC As Range
Dim t1 As String
Dim tper() As Variant
Dim tper2() As Variant
Dim tper3() As Variant
Dim t2 As Long
Dim t3 As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim rr As Range
Dim rrr As Range
Dim myMax As Long
Dim FindMax As Long
Dim myMin As Long
Dim FindMin As Long
Dim strPath As String
a = TextBox1.Value
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Ange Serie")
Exit Sub
End If
aa = TextBox4.Value
If TextBox4.Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Ange Prognosår")
Exit Sub
t1 = TextBox2.Value
If TextBox2.Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Ange Startdatum")
Exit Sub
End If
t2 = Val(t1)
t1 = TextBox3.Value
If TextBox3.Value = "" Then
MsgBox ("Ange Slutdatum")
Exit Sub
End If
t3 = Val(t1)
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
'Sheets("utfall").Activate
strPath = "C:\Users\dmyshe\Desktop\Dmytro\Utfall.xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath, UpdateLinks:=False
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
'Sheets("prognoser").Activate
strPath = "C:\Users\dmyshe\Desktop\Dmytro\Prognoser.xls"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=strPath, UpdateLinks:=False
Else
MsgBox ("Fel")
End If
'Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Sheets("" & aa).Activate
tper = Range("A3:A500")
tper2 = Range("CL3:CL500")
tper3 = Range("CL3:CL500")
For i = 1 To UBound(tper, 1)
tper(i, 1) = year(tper(i, 1))
Next i
For i = 1 To UBound(tper, 1)
If tper(i, 1) >= t2 Then
tper2(i, 1) = i
End If
Next i
FindMin = Application.Min(tper2)
For i = 1 To UBound(tper, 1)
If tper(i, 1) <= t3 And tper(i, 1) <> 1899 Then
tper3(i, 1) = i
End If
Next i
FindMax = Application.Max(tper3)
Set r = Rows(2).Find("" & a, , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireColumn
Range("CM1:CM" & r.Rows.Count) = r.Value
Set rr = Range("CM" & (FindMin + 1) & ":CM" & (FindMax + 1))
Set rrr = Range("A" & (FindMin + 2) & ":A" & (FindMax + 2))
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets("Blad3").Activate
Range("A:A").Cells.Clear
Range("B:B").Cells.Clear
Range("A1") = "Datum"
Range("B1") = "" & a
Range("A1").Font.Bold = True
Range("B1").Font.Bold = True
Range("B2:B" & (rr.Rows.Count + 1)) = rr.Value
Range("A2:A" & (rrr.Rows.Count + 1)) = rrr.Value
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
Workbooks("Utfall").Close False
ElseIf OptionButton2.Value = True Then
Workbooks("Prognoser").Close False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This [link](http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-userform-excel-vba.html) will teach you **How to create a form and write basic VBA code**. For your `User Form Interface`, you are going to need two `textbox` for the date range and `button` to submit the code. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! For your answer. I have used the link you provided and managed to create a user form that satisfies my needs. I have a new problem now. If I want to to extract data for some a specific stock symbol and the user sets the data range I am puzzled with how I can code in VBA. I understand that I need two arrays one with dates and the other with the relevant stock data. Unforntunately, I am completely new to VBA so I do not even know how to if is feasible. My idea is to get position of the relevant of dates and then use them to extract right part of the vector for futures.

Comment: I am glad that i can help. Please create a new question and saw your User form, VBA code and explain the scope(your need).

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-userform-excel-vba.html) will teach you How to create a form and write basic VBA code. For your User Form Interface, you are going to need two textbox for the date range and button to submit the code.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I managed to complete my task using the link you provided and this forum and Google :=) My last question is about error-handling. I use a textbox for stock lookup and what I want is to be able to return an error if stock is not found. The part of code that is responsible for it is here:

Comment: Set r = Rows(2).Find("" & a, , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireColumn

Comment: please display the block of the code.You can do `if r > 0 then msgbox "Sotck is not found" end if`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I get an error message from VBA at this line of code if the stock entered by used is not found :          Set r = Rows(2).Find("" & a, , xlValues, xlWhole).EntireColumn

Comment: from where are you passing stock string to you code? check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249039/find-a-row-from-excel-table-using-vba

Comment: I have a textbox where stock symbol is entered and it is then saved to variable a. That is later used to find correct column which is saved in range r. I tried to check if the range r is empty first and then give an error message. But unfortunately Excel gives me an error message if it can not find stock symbol. So I wonder how can I check if the requested stock can be found before assigning it to the range r.

Comment: All process that you are talking its in the code right? if yes then add the code to you question so i can see what are you doing. whitout looking at the code its very hard to help

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. And thanks again for your help. My code is now added to the initial question.