# Search for numeric value in column and return row

Tags: excel, vba

I stumbled across this useful VBA function: [Find a row from Excel table using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249039/find-a-row-from-excel-table-using-vba?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
Function GetRow(TableName As String, ColumnNum As Long, Key As Variant) As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetRow = Range(TableName) _
        .Rows(WorksheetFunction.Match(Key, Range(TableName).Columns(ColumnNum), 0))
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Set GetRow = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

This function works perfectly fine for texts. However I have serious problems with searching for numbers. I do never get a row back when searching for an integer.

I am using the function like this:

```
    If Not Userform_Input.Text = "" Then
        Set ref = GetRow("table", 3, Userform_Input.Text)

        If Not ref Is Nothing Then
            variable_a = Cells(ref.Row, 2).value
        End If
    End If
```

Looking at the code I can't see the problem. Does anybody else?

Comment: You are always passing a string to your `GetRow()` method. `Userform_Input.Text` will always be a String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try changing your code as below:

```
If Not Userform_Input.Text = "" Then
    Set ref = GetRow("table", 3, cint(Userform_Input.Text)) ' force numeric

    If Not ref Is Nothing Then
        variable_a = Cells(ref.Row, 2).value
    End If
End If
```

maybe that will help