# How do I find different column values for a given row?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to learn VBA after becoming a dinosaur in other languages. The project I'm working on isn't much, mostly a proof-of-concept or training exercise.

I have an Excel table with the columns "Department", "List Markup", "A markup", "B Markup", and "C Markup". I have a form with the user selecting the department, then entering the cost. I want to take the department, find that row, pull the values for mark ups and show the user the list, A, B, and C pricing. Shout out to Chris Neilsen who answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249039/find-a-row-from-excel-table-using-vba) question. It helped, unfortunately not enough. I rewrote his code, but through debugging I've discovered it's not really picking up any rows. I already know what columns I need, just not the rows.

Basically:

```
User selects department
User enters item cost

Search column 1 ("Department") for a match
(Match should exist, because this column is used to populate the first ComboBox
When the match is found, get the row.
Once the row is found, get the markups from the corresponding columns
Output cost times markup for all four prices
```

I'd show you my code, where it's failing, but every change I make is a different error. I think I'm sitting here trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Is your source table limited to just one row per Department? If not, you'll have to loop through the table to find all the rows for that department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your department entries are unique, you can get the row doing the following:

```
deptRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(departmentName, Range("A:A"), 0)
```

assuming that column A contains deparment names, and departmentName is the name of the department you're searching for. The 0 at the end is neccessary to tell Excel to look for exact matches only.

You can actually call any standard worksheet function like this; simply call `Application.WorksheetFunction.functioname()`.

You can then get the value of cells and add them:

```
markup = Cells(deptRow,2)+Cells(deptRow,3)+Cells(deptRow,4)+Cells(deptRow,5)
```

where 2,3,4,5 correspond to columns B,C,D,E.

You could also use the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum` function.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. I appreciate you explaining the code, instead of just giving it. I wanted to do:
`Price A = cost * AMarkup`
etc. but you answered the biggest part of my question and got me moving on, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A simple loop would suffice.

```
Dim strTargetValue As String
strTargetValue = ""

'Simulates a search for "Test 2"
Dim strSearchValue As String
strSearchValue = "Test 2"

Dim intRowNumber As Integer
intRowNumber = 0

Dim intRowCursor As Integer
intRowCursor = 1

Dim bolStopLooking As Boolean
bolStopLooking = False

'Loop until we find the row or find an empty cell.
Do Until intRowNumber > 0 Or bolStopLooking = True

    'Assumes first column is "Department"
    If Rows(intRowCursor).Cells(1).Value = strSearchValue Then

        intRowNumber = intRowCursor

    End If

    If Len(Rows(intRowCursor).Cells(1).Value) = 0 Then

        bolStopLooking = True

    End If

    intRowCursor = intRowCursor + 1

Loop

'Assumes Second Column is target value. Do same for other cells from row that you need.
If intRowNumber > 0 Then

    strTargetValue = Rows(intRowNumber).Cells(2).Value

End If
```