# Function match at VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create 2 combo boxes, but I get the error 1004 match function. There is my code:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCB_data")

Dim i, n As Integer
Me.ComboBox3.Clear

n = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.ComboBox2.Value, sh.Range("1:1"), 0)

For i = 2 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Cells(1, n).EntireColumn)
    Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Cells(i, n).Value
Next i
Me.ComboBox2.ListRows = 20
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PCB_data")
Dim i As Integer
Me.ComboBox3.Clear

For i = 1 To Application.CountA(sh.Range("1:1"))
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem sh.Cells(1, i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: that means the current value of `ComboBox2` isn't found in `sh.Range("1:1")` with an exact match

Comment: Might be easier to use [FIND](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) so you can check if it returns nothing - it will return a reference to the cell rather than the column number so you can then use that inside your COUNTA (`n.EntireColumn`).

Comment: C.f. another example using `WorksheetFunction.Match()`  [Find ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249039/find-a-row-from-excel-table-using-vba/6249386#6249386) to see an example of the `On Error` structure :)